# How to get macro value fom cmake to c++ variable

Tags: c++, cmake, macros

So far the Jenkins file is passing the version to cmake then i would like to cmake to pass the version to a variable in the c++ code.

since PROJECT_VERSION is a builtin variable and its already automaticaly passed to the installer filename with cpack, Iam not sure if this is essential but here is how i define the the macro in cmake:

```
add_compile_definitions(PROJECT_VERSION=${PROJECT_VERSION})
```

then in my .cpp i would like something like this:

```
#ifdef PROJECT_VERSION
#define version "@PROJECT_VERSION@"
#endif
```

If possible i dont want to use a config file like in this tutorial: https://riptutorial.com/cmake/example/32603/using-cmake-to-define-the-version-number-for-cplusplus-usage

Comment: `#ifdef PROJECT_VERSION / #define version "@PROJECT_VERSION@"` makes no sense if `PROJECT_VERSION`  is not a macro. Have you tried `add_compile_definitions(-DPROJECT_VERSION=${PROJECT_VERSION})`? This alone should create a C++ macro definition.

Comment: yup iam pretty close , but thats my error: <command-line>: error: too many decimal points in number
/home/pat/OpenSidescan/src/OpenSidescan/main.cpp:12:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘PROJECT_VERSION’
   12 | #define version PROJECT_VERSION

Comment: sounds like you simply need to wrap your value in quotes. `0.1.0` is not a valid C++ token but `"0.1.0"` is. Or use an integer to represent versions, such as `010`.

Comment: thats not a solution... i guess i will have to use a config file